# Is someone who wrote his name in the Death Note allowed to make the eye deal?

Tags: death-note

Bad example:

Bob Hyrule writes his own name in the death note:

> **Bob Hyrule, peaceful heart attack. Dies peacefully from a heart attack in 20 days.**

So let's say, he then decides to make the Shinigami eye deal. Can he make the Shinigami eye deal? If yes, will he die in 10 days, because he gave his remaining lifespan, or will he still live 20 days?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to some of Kira's tests, if a person can't fulfill his/hers cause of death, he/she will die of a heart attack when the time comes.

If someone write his own name to die of a heart attack in 20 days and then make the shinigami eye deal. It will only have 10 days of lifespan. Therefore that person will die from a heart attack in 10 days because he can't be alive in 20 days.

Comment: But the person already shortened its lifespan, by writing its name in the death note. And the death note has nothing to do with the original lifespan. But thank you very much for answering my question.